# k8s how to exec to distroless container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I want to delete a specific file from a cronJob to the following container, the problem is that when I run exec I got error, how can I exec to distroless container (k8s v1.22.5) and delte the file from a cronJob, which option do we have?

this is the deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: distro
  labels:
    app: distro
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: distro
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: distro
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: edistro
          image: timberio/vector:0.21.X-distroless-libc
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

what I tried is

```sh
kubectl exec -i -t -n apits aor-agent-zz -c tor "--" sh -c "clear; (bash || ash || sh)"
```

The error is:

```sh
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec
```

I tried it out like following

```sh
kubectl debug -it distro-d49b456cf-t85cm --image=ubuntu --target=edistro  --share-processes -n default
```

**And got error:**

```
Targeting container "edistro". If you don't see processes from this container it may be because the container runtime doesn't support this feature. Defaulting debug container name to debugger-fvfxs. error: ephemeral containers are disabled for this cluster (error from server: "the server could not find the requested resource").
```

As I guess (not sure) that our the container runtime doesnt support it which option do we have?

**The answer below** doesn't solve the issue, I need a way to access from **outside the distroless pod** and delete specific file there, how can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point of using `distro-less` is to have a minimal amount of tools/software packaged in the image. This means the removal of unnecessary tools like `shell` from the image.

You may work around using, however it may depend on your objective:

```
kubectl debug -it <POD_TO_DEBUG> --image=<helper-image> --target=<CONTAINER_TO_DEBUG> --share-processes
```

Eg:

```
kubectl debug -it distro-less-pod   --image=ubuntu --target=edistro  --share-processes
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it out like following `kubectl debug -it distro-d49b456cf-t85cm   --image=ubuntu --target=edistro  --share-processes -n default` and get error `Targeting container "edistro". If you don't see processes from this container it may be because the container runtime doesn't support this feature.
Defaulting debug container name to debugger-fvfxs.
error: ephemeral containers are disabled for this cluster (error from server: "the server could not find the requested resource").
`

Comment: AS I guess that our container runtime doesnt support this, which other option do we have?

Comment: the problem is `error: ephemeral containers are disabled for this cluster`

Comment: debug is supported `Kubernetes 1.23`, check the version you running

Comment: you may try enabling ephemeral containers in older version as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61735084/6309601 , I have not tested this

Comment: Thanks but this is not working for me, any other idea how to make it work?

Comment: Have you followed to enable featureGate? If yes, what error you are getting. If not try, following this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/

Comment: Search for ephemeralcontainer in that page, and the steps to enable it in k8s version < 1.23